# How to create toggleable sidenav layout in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am porting my layout from jQuery to React.js. This is very common one that consists of:

- header with toggle button
- sidenav with navigation links
- content whose width adapts to sidenav state.

As you can imagine to achieve that a lot of (css) stuff is going on. I am really confused about possible approaches.

Here is mine:

```
class CoreLayout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      sidenavCollapsed: false
    }
  }

  onSidenavToggle() {
    const { sidenavCollapsed } = this.state

    document.body.classList.toggle('collapsed', !sidenavCollapsed)

    this.setState({ sidenavCollapsed: !sidenavCollapsed })
  }

  render() {
    const { sidenavCollapsed } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Header onSidenavToggle={::this.onSidenavToggle}></Header
        <Sidenav>
        <div className="content">content</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I do all the styling according to class attached to body element:

```
.collapsed .header {}
.collapsed .sidenav {}
.collapsed .content {}
```

Basically it's toggling sidenav width and content margin betwen 220 and 60.

**So...**

Should I pass collapsed property to each of layout elements and add class `collapsed` separately? What I am trying to achieve is [similar to this](http://demo.naksoid.com/elephant/flaming-red/).

What is the correct way of doing `fade-out-in` sidenav items animation? Till now I was using jQuery utilities, but I am not sure if directly using `window.requestAnimationFrame()` is correct. I have tried `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `class` to the navbar on button toggle and animate the transition using css.

See the demo

https://jsfiddle.net/kuLy0g8z/